# Iwebbrowser2 Navigate: No post-data submitted

Tags: c++, post, com, iwebbrowser2

I'm using the `IWebbrowser2` interface in order to call a page and submit some POST-data to it. IE is opened, the page called, but unfortunately no POST-data is submitted (the $_POST-Array on the PHP-Server is empty). Can somebody tell me why?

The relevant parts in the main method:

```
BSTR bstrURL2;
bstrURL2 = SysAllocString(L"http://www.mypage.com/");

// Specify a binary Content-Type.
V_BSTR(&vHeaders) = SysAllocString(
  L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" 
  L"Content-Encoding: UTF-8\r\n");

VARIANT vPostData = {0};
if (Navigate::GetPostData(&vPostData) == NOERROR)
r->Navigate(bstrURL2, &vFlags, &vEmpty, &vPostData, &vHeaders);
```

The GetPostData-method:

```
HRESULT Navigate::GetPostData(LPVARIANT pvPostData)
{
  HRESULT hr;
  LPSAFEARRAY psa;
  LPCTSTR cszPostData = "username=myusername&password=mypassword";
  UINT cElems;
  LPSTR pPostData;

  cElems = lstrlen(cszPostData);

  if (!pvPostData)
  {
    return E_POINTER;
  }

  VariantInit(pvPostData);

  psa = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_UI1, 0, cElems);
  if (!psa)
  {
    return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
  }

  hr = SafeArrayAccessData(psa, (LPVOID*)&pPostData);
  memcpy(pPostData, cszPostData, cElems);
  hr = SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);

  V_VT(pvPostData) = VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1;
  V_ARRAY(pvPostData) = psa;
  return NOERROR;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: `$_POST` is only filled if i.e. a html-form is submited via `method="post"` not by just loading a page.

Comment: Are you setting `vHeaders.vt` to `VT_BSTR`? It's not shown in the code. Anyway, I'd recommend inspecting the actual HTTP request being sent, using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or similar - see if it looks right (add the dump to your question if you are not sure what it's supposed to look like).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your example and it works when I define the type of the `vHeader` variable:

```
// Specify a binary Content-Type.
V_VT(&vHeaders) = VT_BSTR;
V_BSTR(&vHeaders) = SysAllocString(L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Encoding: UTF-8\r\n");
```

See here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/167658